# jQuery DataTables - Access all rows data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and want to copy all rows (save in JavaScript array) upon clicking the header checkbox.

[image: First Page]

**I want to find where jQuery DataTables store the HTML for remaining page of rows**, so I can navigate through JavaScript then check it there or set property checked to true.

Something like this one.

[image]

Other information:

- I use data from an ajax source(`serverside:false`), all data is returned.
- When I click page 1, all the rows remain Checked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find the generated element by jQuery DataTables using this code, and I can copy the whole `tr` element that hides when paging the DataTables.

```
$('#example').DataTable().rows().iterator('row', function(context, index){
    var node = $(this.row(index).node()); 
    //node.context is element of tr generated by jQuery DataTables.
});
```

Comment: how can I make this iterate through every column of the row and compare it with same column of the previous row?

Comment: basically you can access the previous row by having -1 from `$(this.row(index - 1).node())`. you can compare from result

Answer (score 19):

> **SOLUTION**

There are [many methods](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) that could be used for that purpose. You can use [`rows().data()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.data%28%29) to get the data for the selected rows.

Example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

var data = table
    .rows()
    .data();

alert( 'The table has ' + data.length + ' records' );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uko1w3q/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Its also a nice way to access the data in jQuery DataTables, but i want the generated html by jQuery DataTables.., I found it in my answer.., Anyway Thanks!

Comment: You can also use `table.rows().nodes().to$()` to get jQuery collection of all row nodes. You can iterate this collection later and get the HTML for each row. See [`to$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24%28%29) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for this short answer, if you post your edited answer, I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: @janmvtrinidad, if you need nodes and their HTML content, your answer is better. You can accept your own answer as well.

Comment: your answer only shows the count of records, what if one wants to access the data of 1st column of his multi-selected rows in an array?

Comment: @RameshPareek, use `table.columns(0).data()` then.

Answer (score 16):

If you do this:

```
$('#table').DataTable().rows().data();
```

you get a lot of unnecessary data.

If you just want the table data you can do this:

```
$('#table').DataTable().rows().data().toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
tableObject.rows().data()
```

will return all the data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [pageLength](https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength):

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 50
} );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).