# rows().data() function is not returning an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTable.js version 1.10.7 in my application. My intention is to get an Array of row data that was added to the table after initiation. I have followed a modified version of steps as in this documentation - https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

```
<!-- this form is filled and form values are added the datatable on submission-->
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form action="../api/MaterialInPurchaseOrders/Create" id="create-material-in-purchaseOrder" method="POST">
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Material Name</label>
            <select name="MaterialId" class="form-control" id="MaterialList"></select>
            <br />
            <label for="email">Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Quantity" placeholder="eg :- 100">

            <label for="email">Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Cost" placeholder="eg :- 100">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add Material to P/O<span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- this table stores the rows that is being added from the form-->
<div class="col-md-8">
    <table id="materials-in-purchase-order" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Material Id</th>
                <th>Material Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Material Id</th>
                <th>Material Name</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Unit Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" id="get-table-data">Get Table Row Data</button>


<script>

    // the Datatable handler
    var materialsInPurchaseOrder = $("#materials-in-purchase-order").DataTable({
        "dataSrc": "data",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "MaterialId" },
            { "data": "MaterialName" },
            { "data": "Quantity" },
            { "data": "Cost" }
        ]
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // loading list boxes from database to an input selection list box in the form
        loadListBox("../api/Materials/GetMaterials", "#MaterialList", "MaterialId", "MaterialName");

        // on submission of the form the form values gets updated to the Datatable as a row.
        $("#create-material-in-purchaseOrder").on("submit", function (event) {
            var data = {};
            data = getFormValues("#create-material-in-purchaseOrder");
            $("#MaterialList option:selected").each(function () {
                data["MaterialName"] = $(this).html();
            });;

            materialsInPurchaseOrder.row.add(data).draw(false);
            event.preventDefault();
        });


        $("#get-table-data").click(function (event) {
            var materials = materialsInPurchaseOrder.rows().data();
            console.log(materials);

            // looping through each row of the array and doing something
            for (var material in materials) {
                // unable to do this because materials is not an array :(
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

</script>
```

I get the below output for the console.log() instead of an Array

**[Object, context: Array[1], selector: Object, ajax: Object]**

Some research I did,
    [jQuery DataTables - Access all rows data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932680/jquery-datatables-access-all-rows-data)

```
How can I get an Array of DataTable row data.?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation return type of `rows().data()` is `DataTables.Api`. Before print it with `console.log` first convert it to string using `JSON.stringify()`. Because `DataTables.Api` is an object.

Ex:

```
console.log('Materials',JSON.stringify(materials));
```

As per the documentation of [DataTables.Api](https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Api) type `The API object is array-like`

You can access data by row index as follows,

```js
materials[0]
```

This returns data of first row.

Comment: `console.log` can log the object without any problems. It doesn't work like the `alert` function.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved with the help of the answer by @Dushan. This answer demonstrates how the actual code is changed.

I replaced this code

```
for (var material in materials) {
// unable to do this because materials is not an array :(
}
```

with this code

```
// looping through each row until the last row
for (var i=0 ; i < materials.length ; i++) {
console.log(materials[i]);
}
```

The only thing I'm adding to @Dushan's answer is the `for` loop which loops through Objects of the data objects in DataTables.Api to demonstrate the use of DataTables.Api Object.

Summarizing what @Dushan pointed out in the documentation, the return type of the rows().data() method is a `DataTables.Api` object not an `Array`. This is an array like object which is of length equal to the number of rows in the DataTable instance.